# how to create opencart payment gateway module?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart-events

i am new for development bank given some details
Bank ID :
Merchant ID:
Merchant name:
Merchant username/Admin:
Password:
PG Inquiry & Refund Action URL (Production)
https://pgtest3.qcb.gov.qa/QPayOneWeb/EZConnectRequestServlet

PG Redirect Pay URL (Production)
https://pgtest3.qcb.gov.qa/QPayOnePC/PaymentPayServlet

but i did not find any payment gateway module for Qpay Debit Card payment

Anyone please help me?

Payment module or code
Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

These are some tutorial collections for module development that may be helpful to go through the payment module creation:

[How to code single and multi-instance modules](https://webocreation.com/opencart-tutorial-how-to-code-single-and-multi-instance-module/)

[How to create a payment module or extension in Opencart 3? Developer guide Part I of III](https://webocreation.com/how-to-create-a-payment-module-or-extension-in-the-opencart-3-developer-guide-part-i-of-iii/)

[How to create an off-site payment extension in Opencart 3? Part II of III](https://webocreation.com/how-to-create-an-off-site-payment-extension-in-opencart-3-part-ii-of-iii/)

[Opencart 3 development tutorial, multi-instance slider testimonials module](https://webocreation.com/how-to-create-a-payment-module-or-extension-in-the-opencart-3-developer-guide-part-i-of-iii/)